# How do you loop through the contents of a buffer in DX11?

Tags: c++, directx11, buffers

Okay, so I'm currently using the IAGetVertexBuffers() method and I'd like to loop through some of the returned buffers to verify the contents.

However, I'm kind of new to DirectX and C++ in general. I tried using a a simple C++ 11 loop:

```
for (const auto& verts : veBuffer) {
        std::cout << verts << std::endl;
```

But I get an error saying this statement requires a suitable begin statement. Any suggestions would be appreciated at this point.

Comment: I am not a DirectX user, but I guess the problem here is probably that you used a pointer to some allocated memory (`new`/`delete`) as `veBuffer`. Have a look at into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36973045/c-basics-ranged-based-for-loop-and-passing-c-style-arrays-to-functions). So using a regular for loop (`for (int i=0; i<SIZE, ++i)`) should already fix your problem.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use a `std::vector` as `veBuffer`, resize it to the necessary buffer size and pass the data pointer to your DirectX function with `veBuffer.data()`.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues.  First you need to make sure that `veBuffer` has the correct type, so that probably means you need to cast it to *pointer to vertex*:

```
const auto vertices = reinterpret_cast<const Vertex*>(reBuffer);
```

Second a range-based `for`-loop needs to know where the range ends and giving it a raw pointer does not provide that information, so you cannot use it here.  Instead you will need to know how many vertices there are and use a normal `for`-loop:

```
const size_t numVerts = 32;
for (size_t i = 0; i < numVerts; ++i) {
    const Vertex& vert = vertices[i];
    ...
}
```